# При создании бота в телеграмме для пересылки сообщения по ключевому слову

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot

```py
import telebot

bot = telebot.TeleBot('token')

my_id = int('1047621278')


@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    print(message)


@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: 'ключевое слово' in message.text.lower(), content_types=['text'])
def repeat_all_messages(message):
    bot.forward_message(my_id, message.chat.id, message.id)


bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\sharafutdinovbd\PycharmProjects\bottelegramm\bot telega2.py", line 18, in <module>
    bot.polling(none_stop=True)
  File "C:\Users\sharafutdinovbd\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 455, in polling
    self.__threaded_polling(none_stop, interval, timeout, long_polling_timeout)
  File "C:\Users\sharafutdinovbd\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 513, in __threaded_polling
    raise e
  File "C:\Users\sharafutdinovbd\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 478, in __threaded_polling
    polling_thread.raise_exceptions()
  File "C:\Users\sharafutdinovbd\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\telebot\util.py", line 88, in raise_exceptions
    raise self.exception_info
  File "C:\Users\sharafutdinovbd\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\telebot\util.py", line 69, in run
    task(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\sharafutdinovbd\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 296, in __retrieve_updates
    self.process_new_updates(updates)
  File "C:\Users\sharafutdinovbd\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 357, in process_new_updates
    self.process_new_messages(new_messages)
  File "C:\Users\sharafutdinovbd\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 383, in process_new_messages
    self._notify_command_handlers(self.message_handlers, new_messages)
  File "C:\Users\sharafutdinovbd\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 2127, in _notify_command_handlers
    if self._test_message_handler(message_handler, message):
  File "C:\Users\sharafutdinovbd\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 2093, in _test_message_handler
    if not self._test_filter(message_filter, filter_value, message):
  File "C:\Users\sharafutdinovbd\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 2114, in _test_filter
    return test_cases.get(message_filter, lambda msg: False)(message)
  File "C:\Users\sharafutdinovbd\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 2111, in <lambda>
    'func': lambda msg: filter_value(msg)
  File "C:\Users\sharafutdinovbd\PycharmProjects\bottelegramm\bot telega2.py", line 13, in <lambda>
    @bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: '@temamorg' in message.text.lower())
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'lower'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: может проще будет `@bot.message_handler(regexp="пример")`?

Comment: Помогло!!!!
Спасибо!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибка `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'lower'` значит что ваш `message.text.lower()` ничего не возвращает, как можно что то делать с пустотой?) `¯\_( ͡° ͜ʖ ͡°)_/¯¯\_(ツ)_/¯`
Правильное построение бота -

```
import telebot

bot = telebot.TeleBot('token')

my_id = 1047621278


@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Привeт")

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def repeat_all_messages(message):
    if 'ключевое слово' in message.text.lower():
        bot.forward_message(my_id, message.chat.id, message.id)


bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Comment: Дело в том, что мне нужно было по ключевому слову переслать сообщения!

Comment: Сейчас дополню)